# Specifying Python version within Snakemake using script parameter

Tags: python, snakemake

I have some code that I am incorporating into a Snakemake pipeline. I also want to be able to run the code independently of Snakemake, so I want to write flexible code. I have a config file that can be read by Snakemake and an alternative config file that will be parsed if the code is run outside Snakemake.

I had the following structure in a rule in my Snakemake file:

```
rule some_rule:
    input:
        input_file
    output:
        output_file
    script:
        runfile.py
```

and then in `runfile.py` I tested to see if the script was being run within Snakemake as follows:

```
if 'snakemake' in globals():
    # Get config params from Snakemake
else:
    # Load config params from alternative config file
```

This was fine, except that I am working within a virtual environment and the Python version I want to use is different from the one Snakemake uses by default.
So I had to restructure the rule as follows:

```
rule some_rule:
    input:
        input_file
    output:
        output_file
    shell:
        /path/to/python runfile.py
```

but now because I am using `shell` instead of `script` I don't have access to the  `global` parameter 'snakemake' in my python file.

So my question is either

(i) Can I specify a Python version and still use `script`?

or

(ii) Can I use `shell` but still access the 'snakemake' object within the script that will allow me to test whether or not the script is being run in a Snakemake pipeline?

Comment: Granted that I don't know enough detail about your task, wouldn't it be better to make `runfile.py` independent of where the config file comes from? Either add a command line option taking a file as input or add command line options for the individual parameters. I think in this way you make `runfile.py` more self-contained, portable and easier to test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Conda - it would both provide fine-grained control over execution contexts and improve the pipeline reproducibility. See [Documentation](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/deployment.html#integrated-package-management).

First, you'll need an environment definition YAML file. For example,

**envs/py37.yml**

```
channels:
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - python=3.7
```

Add in any other requirements you need in that file. Then your rule would be

**Snakefile**

```
rule some_rule:
    input:
        input_file
    output:
        output_file
    conda:
        envs/py37.yml
    script:
        runfile.py
```

Lastly, you now need to use the additional flag `--use-conda` when launching this job, e.g.,

**shell**

```
snakemake --use-conda output_file
```