# Python version in a bash PBS job

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7, snakemake, pbs

I am biologist, so I am really sorry if this is a very basic question and I am not able to use the correct jargon.

I have to launch a PBS job which consists of a Bash script in which I launch a Snakemake workflow.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
# -- coding: utf-8 --

#PBS -q blade
#PBS -N analysis
#PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=12,mem=28gb,walltime=96:00:00
#set -o errexit
#set -o nounset
#set -o pipefail
#set -o xtrace
. /etc/profile.d/spack.sh
. ${HOME}/.bashrc

cd ~/Documents/Analysis
mkdir results

conda activate struo2
snakemake --use-conda --cores 10 
conda deactivate
```

There are some Bash commands, such as `cd` and `mkdir`, so that I chose the shebang `#!/usr/bin/bash`. In latter steps, I launch a Snakemake workflow, and get the error `UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other`, I believe it is because the programs launched by Snakefile require Python 2.7, while the default is 3.6.

I understand that we can specify the Python version in the shebang, like `#!/usr/bin/python2.7`, but as these commands are to be run in Bash, I do not think this is suitable. Furthermore, I am working in the laboratory computer, so I am not allowed to change default settings and I do not have superuser privileges.

Comment: Your line `cd /Documents/Analysis` looks as if it has a typo: there is probably a tilde missing: `cd ~/Documents/Analysis`

Comment: Thank you @Michael, I changed that. But that is actually not the problem, as the path in my original script is different (and which I used in other scripts, it works). I had only changed for something shorter for clarity.

Comment: Do the commands work, if you execute them line by line in a command line? If yes, there are a couple of variables that are set differently for a script and the command line. You can compare the outputs of `which python`. And maybe of `echo $PATH`

Comment: Although the `source` lines (the ones starting with a `. `) look as if they could do roughly the right thing 

Comment: Have you seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55923707/specifying-python-version-within-snakemake-using-script-parameter)?

Comment: Thank you again @Michael . I managed to get Python2.7 in my local and executed the commands line by line; I still get the same error. So it is probably something else and I need to think differently. As I get most of the things pre built (including the Snakefile), I poorly understand them and perhaps I should study more.

Comment: Also thank you very much for the link to the other question.